# How to properly encode special characters in a REST API url

Tags: api, rest, url, urlencode, url-encoding

EDIT: The NHTSA docs, as CBroe points out, say to replace an ampersand with an underscore. However, I'm also getting an error with forward slashes (albeit a different one, page not found, because it's decoding the slash), for example the make 'EXISS/SOONER':

http://www.nhtsa.gov/webapi/api/Recalls/vehicle/modelyear/1997/make/EXISS%2FSOONER?format=json

And replacing the ampersand with an underscore no longer results in an error message, but in zero results returned, which should not be the case.

ORIGINAL POST:

I'm trying to download the content from the following URL:

http://www.nhtsa.gov/webapi/api/Recalls/vehicle/modelyear/1997/make/s&s?format=json

And the site returns the following error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
```

The problem is the ampersand; a similar request for a different car make works:

http://www.nhtsa.gov/webapi/api/Recalls/vehicle/modelyear/1997/make/toyota?format=json

I have verified from a different endpoint that S&S is a valid make for the API.

Based on stackoverflow answers, I've tried all the following without success:

http://www.nhtsa.gov/webapi/api/Recalls/vehicle/modelyear/1997/make/s%26s?format=json

http://www.nhtsa.gov/webapi/api/Recalls/vehicle/modelyear/1997/make/s%26amp;s?format=json

http://www.nhtsa.gov/webapi/api/Recalls/vehicle/modelyear/1997/make/s%26amp%3Bs?format=json

Comment: http://www.nhtsa.gov/webapi/Default.aspx?Recalls/API/83#divNotes says an ampersand was to be replaced with an underscore; however, for the example URL you mentioned that just yields a “No results found for this request” message in the JSON returned. If that is not the expected result, then I suggest you contact NHTSA for clarification/fixing of the error.

Comment: Thanks, CBroe, that's good to know, and the request should return a result; also, makes with other special characters like parentheses and slashes result in an error.

Comment: As of Oct. 2018 this still seems to be an issue!